# akka and the benefits of at-most-once message semantics

Tags: akka

I'm going through this tutorial: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/guide/tutorial_3.html and don't quite understand when the at-most-once message semantics is preferable, since although we get performance gains, we lose resiliency of messages. It looks like the justification for this trade-off is explained here:

*We only want to report success once the order has been actually fully processed and persisted. The only entity that can report success is the application itself, since only it has any understanding of the domain guarantees required. No generalized framework can figure out the specifics of a particular domain and what is considered a success in that domain.
In this particular example, we only want to signal success after a successful database write, where the database acknowledged that the order is now safely stored. For these reasons Akka lifts the responsibilities of guarantees to the application itself, i.e. you have to implement them yourself with the tools that Akka provides. This gives you full control of the guarantees that you want to provide. Now, let’s consider the message ordering that Akka provides to make it easy to reason about application logic.*

, but I don't quite understand what it means. Any help in understanding this or some other considerations for this decision is appreciated.

I read this thread [RPC semantics what exactly is the purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330067/rpc-semantics-what-exactly-is-the-purpose) which seemed to offer a clear definition of the use cases of at-most-once semantics with payment submission as the example of something you wouldn't want to duplicate.  But from the quoted paragraph above, it sounds like the messages would be sent out into the ether with no regard for an ack that confirms success or failure of message delivery. I'm wondering if both descriptions of at-most-once semantics is correct to their respective domains, how to get the behavior in the other stackoverflow thread with an acknowledgement from akka.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All anything that doesn't know about the domain can offer with at-least or exactly-once delivery is that the message has been delivered (a guarantee that the message has been processed is also possible and practical in at least some (but not all) scenarios).  This is fine if it's what you want, but conflating this with something higher level (like "order has been durably recorded") is virtually certain to lead to essentially impossible to debug bugs down the road.

At-least-once is quite easy to accomplish in Akka by having messages include a field containing an `ActorRef` to which to send an ack (or other response) and having the sender resend unacked messages (because it's eminently possible for the ack to get dropped, these retries are what leads to at-least-once).  The ask pattern (included with Akka) provides this at a high level: in Akka Typed this is done by specifying an adapter function so that when actor A asks actor B, B can send a message in its protocol and A gets a message in its protocol (avoiding a chicken-and-egg problem); if no response is received in a specified timeframe, the adapter causes a failure message to be sent to actor A which (for at-least-once semantics would dictate that A eventually retry the message).  The critical thing to remember is that it's actor B (or its designee: e.g. if B farms the work out to a worker actor, that worker actor can send the acknowledgement to A) that decides whether and when to respond, not Akka.

If doing at-least-once, it's very useful to design the messaging protocol around idempotence: a retry of a successful message doesn't result in a side effect beyond an ack.  Idempotence plus at-least-once has been referred to as "effectively-once" and it's a lot easier to implement and lighter-weight than exactly-once.

[Akka's docs on interaction patterns](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html) describe various messaging patterns in Akka, with a discussion of advantages and disadvantages.  Fairly recently, especially when using Akka Cluster and Akka Persistence, there is a fairly heavyweight implementation of [reliable delivery](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/reliable-delivery.html): in the maximum reliability mode (using Akka Persistence), because each message sent in this way is persisted to a datastore (e.g. local disk, or cassandra, or...), the latency for a message send is severely increased.